# Question about the definition of Associative Pseudorandom Permutation

Tags: permutation, pseudo-random-permutation

In question about [associative pseudo-random permutation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51570/impossibility-of-associative-pseudorandom-permutation#) the definition uses:

$f(k_1, f(k_2, m)) = f(f(k_1, k_2), m)$

What is defined by that? No luck with google so far.
As far as I know a permutation is defined by item number at a certain index. If $f$ is a table the item number count would be higher than the number of columns/rows which would result in invalid indices.
Or is it a permutation in each row and column? Number of rows and columns need to be equal then. Would be some kind of Latin-square matrix.
If that's the case the definition would result in a symmetric matrix which would be the same permutation in each direction.

Comment: Look up the definition of a *pseudorandom permutation*, for starters.

Comment: There had never been such thing, otherwise such silverbullet to PKC would have already been discovered! And the title of the linked question is clear enough: The "Impossibility" of ...

Comment: @DannyNiu The question is about what the definition means, not about whether such objects exist.

Comment: @DannyNiu you write '(I'm not sure if it'd be impossible)' in this thread. Can you please define what $f$ and $k1$,$k2$,$m$ stand for. I'm fine with just two words like table,function, permutation, index, variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $f(k_1, f(k_2, m)) = f(f(k_1, k_2), m)$
>
> What is defined by that?

$f$ is just a binary operator written in the notation of a function.

Suppose $f: P \times P \rightarrow P$ is a binary operator taking 2 permutations encoded as bitstrings as operands and produce another permutation (also encoded as bitstring) as result, the associativity can be illustrated by replacing $f(a,b)$ as $a+b$, and the original equation will be:

$k_1 + (k_2 + m) = (k_1 + k_2) + m$

Here, suppose we're in a digital signature scheme, the $k_1$ and $(k_1+k_2)$ will be the public key, $k_2$ will be the private key, and $m$ is the (digest of) message being signed.

And that, is just my wishful thinking that public-key cryptography can be as simple as a one-year-old's mind.